# Native iOS effect in @react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

While scroll list need to show native effect like as AppStore app in iOS. (Gradient effect for current screen)

bottom-tab provide this effect?

[image]

Thanks